Sharp Sobolev trace inequalities on Riemannian manifolds with boundaries
For $n \geq3$, let $(M,g)$ be smooth $n$-dimensional, compact, Riemannian manifold with a smooth boundary. Then there exists some constant $A=A(M,g)>0$ such that, for all $u \in H^1(M)$
\begin{equation}
    \Big( \int_{\partial M} |u|^q\,ds_g   \Big)^\frac{2}{q} \leq S\int_M |\nabla_g u|^2\,dv_g+A \int_{\partial M} u^2 \,ds_g,
\end{equation}
where $dv_g$ denotes the volume form of $(M,g)$ , $ds_g$ denotes induced volume on $\partial M$ and $\frac{1}{S} =\frac{n-2}{2} \sigma^{\frac{1}{n-1}}_n$, $\sigma_n$ denotes the volume of unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $q=\frac{2(n-1)}{(n-2)}$. (link at publisher website)
Another proposition (prop 1.2) from the same above mentioned article says that
for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists some constant $A(\varepsilon)$ depending on $\varepsilon, M$ and $g$ such that for all $u \in H^1(M)$
\begin{equation}
    \Big( \int_{\partial M} |u|^q\,ds_g   \Big)^\frac{2}{q} \leq (S+\varepsilon)\int_M |\nabla_g u|^2\,dv_g+A(\varepsilon) \int_{\partial M} u^2 \,ds_g.
\end{equation}
My questions are:

How to find the explicit form of $A$?
suppose I am taking a three dimensional unit cube. There I consider a spherical solid part in the middle of the cube and remaining part is pore part. Can I apply these results in this pore part? Note that solid part does not touch the boundary of cube.

